# How to fix this Flutter Doctor "Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to " macos?

Tags: flutter, macos, dart

I'm getting this warning after using "Flutter Doctor" command after the installation of Dart using brew tap dart-lang/dart on **MacOS Big Sur**

> Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 11.7.2 20G1020 darwin-x64,
> locale
> en-GB)
> ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
> /usr/local/Cellar/dart/2.19.1/libexec/bin/dart, which is not inside your
> current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/puneet/development/flutter.
> Consider adding /Users/puneet/development/flutter/bin to the front of your
> path.

Can you anyone tell me how can i resolve this issue?

I'm trying avoid this warning and run a code on android studio developed on flutter framework.

Comment: Uninstall/untap dart from brew. Flutter comes packaged with its own version of dart. You do not need to install another version of dart in addition to the one flutter provides for you.

Comment: Or do what it says. It depends on which Dart you want to use.

Answer (score 127):

I resolve this warning by just uninstalling the dart sdk using this command -

```
brew uninstall dart
```

Since dart sdk already comes with flutter installation, you need not to install it seperately.

Comment: Thanks I was literally confused what to do.
macOS Ventura 13.4
MacBook Pro 14" 2021

Answer (score 27):

#### SOLVED

when you update your flutter to the latest version this warning comes in your flutter doctor output:-

[image: IMAGE OF WARNING]

for solving this just go and open .zshrc and after that check your flutter bin path is like this:-

[image: IMAGE OF PATH]

#### change your path into this:-

[image: IMAGE OF PATH]

and then run flutter doctor again... PROBLEM SOLVED ☺️

[image: ERROR SOLVED]

Comment: where to find this .zhrc file in my Mac?

Comment: just go to finder then press ( cmnd + shift + . )  then all hide files will be unhide then find .zshrc file ☺️

Comment: You can also open zhrc by executing the command sudo nano ~/.zshrc on your terminal.

Comment: This solved my problem. But what is the difference earlier path and new path

Comment: You can open your .zshrc file by typing this command: "open -e ~/.zshrc"

Comment: This worked in my case, thank you @UsaidAsif the only thing I did extra is we need to kill the old terminal open the new one and then type `flutter doctor`.

Answer (score 13):

If you downloaded the flutter-sdk and also installed dart separately, here's the simple answer:

1. Open your terminal
2. Type the following, then press 'enter':

   ```
   brew uninstall dart
   ```
3. Brew will then uninstall dart
4. Once uninstalled, type the following, then press 'enter':

   ```
   flutter doctor -v
   ```
5. Flutter Doctor should report back

   ```
    No issues found!
   ```

The Dart SDK is bundled with Flutter, so it isn't necessary to install Dart separately.

Answer (score 6):

Here a solution:

**export PATH="/Users/my_user_name/development/flutter/bin:$PATH"**

where **"/Users/my_user_name/development/flutter/bin"** is in your message from:

flutter doctor

Answer (score 2):

this 2023 solution. Thanks god.

```
brew uninstall dart-sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Flutter` framework also contains `Dart`. So, if you already installed `Dart` separately on your OS, remove `Dart` and its Path from your system. You should have only one Path that is: `/Users/puneet/development/flutter/bin`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: They were asking how to do that and you are only telling what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Check your environment variable,if dart path exist remove it.
Because dart executable exist in flutter and dart-sdk also.Add only path flutter bin.It work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue.

The problem was that I didn't realise it was case-sensitive. The path in my .zshrc was in lowercase, but my **Development** folder started with a capital D.

I changed my folder name from **Development** to **development**, and everything worked fine.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

New name package..
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/dart-sdk

```
brew install dart-sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

The same issue happened to me after upgrading Flutter from 3.1 to 3.16. Can not create new flutter project. `flutter create app_name` shows this error: Generating synthetic localizations package failed with 1 error:

PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'pubspec.yaml' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

`flutter doctor` shows this output:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel master, 3.16.0-19.0.pre, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64,
locale en-AU)
! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to
/Users/userName/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not inside your current Flutter
SDK checkout at /users/elmar/flutter. Consider adding
/users/userName/flutter/bin to the front of your path.
! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to /Users/userName/flutter/bin/dart,
which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at
/users/userName/flutter. Consider adding /users/userName/flutter/bin to the front of your path.

1. For solving the warning related to dart, enter this command and uninstall dart:

   brew uninstall dart
2. Now the warning regarding the Flutter path. This is happening due to some changes in the path of the latest Flutter versions. Seems like someone in Flutter team had some spare time and wanted to create a problem noone ever asked to have. For me, in MacOS accepted path structure for all older Flutter versions was like this before:

   export PATH=$PATH:/users/userName/flutter/bin

Note that it depends on the folder location and maybe sligthly different for you. Better check it with this commmand:

```
which flutter
```

Now after upgrading to Flutter 3.16.0-19.0.pre, the same path structure is no longer working. Working path is now like this (The Flutter path is case sensitive now and PATH variable is moved to the end):

```
export PATH=“/Users/userName/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

You have 2 ways to correct it:
Option a)
Use this command and edit the path in opening .zshrc file:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Option b)
Directly enter the new format Flutter path into the terminal. For instance, I enter this path:

```
export PATH=“/Users/userName/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

Now you may need to close and open the terminal before checking, to make sure that the terminal is using the updated pathes.

If the same issue happening with the `fvm` you can use this commands:

```
dart pub global activate fvm
fvm list // Check versions    
fvm use stable --force     // Select one of the Flutter versions from the list, for example 'stable' (--force only necessary if you are outside Flutter project folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve this problem
My dart path on environmental variable was look like (Both user and system variable)

> `C:\src\dart-sdk\bin`
> Now I change it to
> C:\src\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe
> and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of case sensitive. You can check like that

```
which flutter
```

If result is like that
/users/***/developments/flutter/bin/flutter"

export path like that

```
export PATH=/Users/***/developments/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Delete dart sdk from C drive and also from Environment Veriable's path, it is done!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this is occuour because you may be use a version manager like fvm. when a FLUTTER_HOME is a simbolic link this warning shows up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10
My project was in

C:\Users\Oleksii\AndroidStudioProjects\FlutterProjects\monitoring\flutter
[image]

I just moved FlutterProjects to flutter folder:

C:\Users\Oleksii\flutter\FlutterProjects\monitoring>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

run `which flutter`

if the outcome like one of those :

> export PATH="/users/.../flutter/bin"
> export PATH="/users/.../flutter/bin:$PATH"

change it to :

> export PATH="/Users/.../flutter/bin:$PATH"

'Users' is case sensitive most time